# Get-MsolServicePrincipalCredential with the right propertys

Tags: azure, powershell

With the code below I can get a list of client secrets listed, but trying to use propertys as in the example here as you could do for example if you want to list certificates on your server won't work. I tried to google on but can't find any examples.

With -property no matter which one you pick in this example the return would be nothing.

```
Connect-MsolService
         $applist = Get-MsolServicePrincipal -all | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.DisplayName -notlike "*Microsoft*") -and ($_.DisplayName -notlike "autohost*") -and ($_.ServicePrincipalNames -notlike "*localhost*") }
    foreach ($appentry in $applist) {
    $principalId = $appentry.AppPrincipalId
    $principalName = $appentry.DisplayName

   Get-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $principalId -ReturnKeyValues $false | ? { $_.Type -eq "Password" } | Select-Object -Property DisplayName
```

If we skip the property, it would look like:

```
Type      : 
Password Value     :  
KeyId     : 642ee910-9b17-4d17-93d4-0192f3c1f855 
StartDate : 2018-05-25 08:22:37 
EndDate   : 2019-05-25 08:22:37 
Usage     : Verify
```

I want in the same list format just with more propertys so I can recyle another script to upload the data to a sharepoint list.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
$clientsecrets = @()
$applist = Get-MsolServicePrincipal -all | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.DisplayName -like "*SI*") -or ($_.DisplayName -like "*FD*") -or ($_.DisplayName -like "*AP*") -and ($_.DisplayName -notlike "*Microsoft*") -and ($_.DisplayName -notlike "autohost*") -and ($_.ServicePrincipalNames -notlike "*localhost*") }
        foreach ($appentry in $applist) {
        $principalId = $appentry.AppPrincipalId
        $principalName = $appentry.DisplayName
    

       $clientsecret = Get-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $principalId -ReturnKeyValues $false | ? { $_.Type -eq "Password" } | % { $principalName, $principalId;, ($enddate = $_.EndDate.ToString()) } | select {$principalName}, {$principalId}, {$enddate}
     
     $clientsecret | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'principalId' -Value $principalId
     $clientsecret | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'principalName' -Value $principalName
        $clientsecrets+=$clientsecret

      }
```

Using an array and using add-member did put it in a format where I could use and read and add it to the sharepoint list.